# Using Free Monad with Either

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, either, free-monad

I have two DSLs - `EmployeeAction` and `ContactAction`. Here are my traits (Actions)

Complete Gist: [link](https://gist.github.com/arjunswaj/4c3c7789ccdd9f832f2cf16690b57cbf)

```
sealed trait EmployeeAction[R]
case class GetEmployee(id: Long) extends EmployeeAction[Either[Error, Employee]]

sealed trait ContactAction[R]
case class GetAddress(empId: Long) extends ContactAction[Either[Error, Address]]
```

I've used `cats`' `Coproduct` and `Inject` here is my program to get manager's address:

```
type Program = Coproduct[EmployeeAction, ContactAction, A]

def findManagerAddress(employeeId: Long)
               (implicit EA: EmployeeActions[Program],
                CA: ContactActions[Program]): Free[Program, Address] = {
  import EA._, CA._
  for {
    employee <- getEmployee(employeeId)
    managerAddress <- getAddress(employee.managerId)
  } yield managerAddress
}
```

The above doesn't compile because `getEmployee` returns an `Either[Error, Employee]`. How do I handle this in `Free` for comprehension?

I tried wrapping up with `EitherT` monad transformer as below, it shows no errors in IntelliJ but it fails upon building.

```
for {
  employee <- EitherT(getEmployee(employeeId))
  managerAddress <- EitherT(getAddress(employee.managerId))
} yield managerAddress
```

Below is the error:

```
[scalac-2.11] /local/home/arjun/code/Free/src/FreeScalaScripts/src/free/program/Program.scala:71: error: no type parameters for method apply: (value: F[Either[A,B]])cats.data.EitherT[F,A,B] in object EitherT exist so that it can be applied to arguments (cats.free.Free[free.Program,Either[free.Error,free.Employee]])
[scalac-2.11]  --- because ---
[scalac-2.11] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[scalac-2.11]  found   : cats.free.Free[free.Program,Either[free.Error,free.Employee]]
[scalac-2.11]  required: ?F[Either[?A,?B]]
[scalac-2.11]       employee <- EitherT(getEmployee(employeeId))
[scalac-2.11]                   ^
```

How do I deal with Either in for comprehension and how to propagate the errors to the caller? I want to know for which all employee ids the call failed.

Comment: What's the compile error for `EitherT`?

Comment: @ZiyangLiu I've updated the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

`EitherT` takes a `F[Either[A, B]]` but you have a `Free[Program, Either[Error, Employee]]`, which is not compatible.

The solution to create a type alias for `Free[Program, A]`:

```
type MyAlias[A] = Free[Program, A]
```

Then make `getEmployee` return `MyAlias[Either[Error, Employee]]` and same for `getAddress`.

Comment: Actually,  [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/arjunswaj/4c3c7789ccdd9f832f2cf16690b57cbf) of what I have. Even with Type Alias the for comprehension is not working as EitherT and Free cannot be combined. I want to know how to handle this.